# SQL Server Query - Selecting values BETWEEN 2 Dates

Tags: sql-server

I am getting some problems in getting one query done.

I have 2 strings which are suppose to store time in this format (**HH:mm** Ex: Date1 -> '20:20' and Date2 -> '21:20'). I want to get the current time (CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108) -> to get only 'HH:mm') and get all rows that are between the current date.

The idea is: Select * where "getdate() between date1 and date2", this is not a query, only the idea.

Edit:

```
Time1   Time2
08:20   09:05
09:05   09:50
10:05   10:50
10:50   11:35
11:45   12:30
12:30   13:15
13:35   14:20
```

Thx for the solutions, I will check them, but one question how can i "fix" the problem when it's 9:05 (for example), I will get both rows/records, I assume i have to go to the seconds right?

Comment: You may want to post some real date values from your table, if they are not big secret. table structure can be better.

Answer (score 1):

The following constructs two `DATETIME`s, based on TIME only, from your input strings (`@TimeStr1 and @TimeStr2`) then strips the `DATE` part from `GETDATE()`. Then you can easily do the query with `BETWEEN`.

```
DECLARE 
  @CurrentTime DATETIME,
  @TimeStr1 VARCHAR(12),
  @TimeStr2 VARCHAR(12),
  @Time1 DATETIME,
  @Time2 DATETIME

SET @TimeStr1 = '20:20'  
SET @TimeStr2 = '21:20'  
SET @Time1 = CAST('1900-01-01 ' + @TimeStr1 AS DATETIME)
SET @Time2 = CAST('1900-01-01 ' + @TimeStr2 AS DATETIME)
-- The following strips the date from datetime leaving only a time
SET @CurrentTime = DateAdd(ss, DateDiff(ss, DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, GetDate()), 0), GetDate()), 0)

SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE @CurrentTime BETWEEN  @Time1 AND  @Time2
```

This will work for all versions of SQL SERVER. If you are using a version >= 2008 then a simpler version of the above exists.

If you are worried about overlaps (eg your "09:05" problem) use the following query that avoids the problem by using > and <= rather then BETWEEN

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE @CurrentTime > @Time1 AND  @CurrentTime <= @Time2
```